# How can I change the current directory in a thread-safe manner in Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, working-directory

I'm using `Thread::Pool::Simple` to create a few working threads. Each working thread does some stuff, including a call to `chdir` followed by an execution of an external Perl script (from the `jbrowse` genome browser, if it matters). I use `capturex` to call the external script and die on its failure.

I discovered that when I use more then one thread, things start to be messy. after some research. it seems that the current directory of some threads is not the correct one.

Perhaps `chdir` propagates between threads (i.e. isn't thread-safe)?
Or perhaps it's something with `capturex`?

So, how can I safely set the working directory for each thread?

** UPDATE **

Following the suggestions to change dir while executing, I'd like to ask how exactly should I pass these two commands to `capturex`?

currently I have:

```
my @args = ( "bin/flatfile-to-json.pl", "--gff=$gff_file", "--tracklabel=$track_label", "--key=$key", @optional_args );
capturex( [0], @args );
```

How do I add another command to `@args`?
Will `capturex` continue die on errors of any of the commands?

Comment: You might want to consider using processes instead of threads, e.g. using [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager), so that each worker can have its own current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can solve your "how do I chdir in the child before running the command" problem pretty easily by abandoning `IPC::System::Simple` as not the right tool for the job.

Instead of doing

```
my $output = capturex($cmd, @args);
```

do something like:

```
use autodie qw(open close);
my $pid = open my $fh, '-|';
unless ($pid) { # this is the child
  chdir($wherever);
  exec($cmd, @args) or exit 255;
}
my $output = do { local $/; <$fh> };
# If child exited with error or couldn't be run, the exception will
# be raised here (via autodie; feel free to replace it with 
# your own handling)
close ($fh);
```

If you were getting a list of lines instead of scalar output from `capturex`, the only thing that needs to change is the second-to-last line (to `my @output = <$fh>;`).

More info on forking-open is in [perldoc perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Safe-Pipe-Opens).

The good thing about this in preference to `capture("chdir wherever ; $cmd @args")` is that it doesn't give the shell a chance to do bad things to your `@args`.

### Updated code (doesn't capture output)

```
my $pid = fork;
die "Couldn't fork: $!" unless defined $pid;
unless ($pid) { # this is the child
  chdir($wherever);
  open STDOUT, ">/dev/null"; # optional: silence subprocess output
  open STDERR, ">/dev/null"; # even more optional
  exec($cmd, @args) or exit 255;
}
wait;
die "Child error $?" if $?;
```

Comment: +1 thanks hobbs, I will try that. a couple of follow-ups: what is `my $output = do { local $/; <$fh> };` I actually don't care about the output of the executed command, unless it fails, soc an I omit this? Also, can `use autodie...` be set locally in the scope of the the subroutine or should I put it at the top of my script?

Comment: @David if you don't need the input, then you don't need `open`, or reading the output, just `fork`, `chdir`, `exec`. Updating my answer...

Answer (score 2):

I don't *think* "current working directory" is a per-thread property. I'd *expect* it to be a property of the process.

It's not clear exactly why you need to use `chdir` at all though. Can you not launch the external script setting the *new* process's working directory appropriately instead? That sounds like a more feasible approach.

Comment: you mean like `capture("cd desired-dir; perl external-script")`?

Comment: Each thread actually runs a few external scripts. A precondition for all of them is that the current directory is the "right one", so I thought to change it once at the beginning of the thread sub, then call all the external scripts as normal. Do you suggest to call each external script like ysth suggested?

Comment: @David B: Why not create another script which changes directory and runs all the required scripts? But yes, basically if you only perform the `cd` in the new process, you won't run into conflicts.

Comment: @David B: If flatfile-to-json is your own script, why not just add an extra parameter which says what directory to change to?